# Prove the matrix is irreducible, stochastic and primitive or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix I have below is following which non-negative matrices rules and prove?
irreducible?
stochastic?
primitive?
All eigenvalues of the matrix are in a unit circle or not?

```
0.9 0.1 0   0   0
0   0.9 0.1 0   0
0   0   0.9 0.1 0
0   0   0   0.9 0.1
0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is not irreducible since state 5 is absorbing and states 1-4 are transient. It is stochastic since the rows sum to 1 and the entries are nonnegative. It is not primitive since $P^n(5,j) = 0$ for all $j \neq 5$. And all the eigenvalues of the matrix are on the diagonal since the matrix is triangular, so yes, they are in the unit disc.

Comment: In the closed unit disk, not on the unit circle.

Comment: so it is not unit circle right?

Comment: They are **in** the unit circle, but not **on** the unit circle. (Only one of them is on the circle)

Comment: 0.9  0.1  0    0  , 
    0    0.9  0.1  0 ,
    0    0    0.9  0.1 ,
    0.1  0    0    0.9 

I am not good about math and i read so much about non negative metrics but it is like Chinese for me.here the matrix is double stochastic as row and column sums =1.but still coudnt understand  irreducible? and primitive? very well.
Could you correct me please! this matrix is  irreducible and primitive and all eigenvalues of matrix are in the unit circle right.

Comment: It may help you to see some equivalent formulations of irreducibility. See http://planetmath.org/ReducibleMatrix.html. I used property 2 for your example. Draw the directed graph corresponding to the matrix, then the matrix is irreducible iff it is possible to travel from any node to any other node. Your example fails this condition because it is not possible to travel away from node 5.

Comment: As for seeing the matrix is primitive, recall the definition. A matrix is primitive if there is $k>0$ such that $P^k$ has all strictly positive entries. Looking at your matrix though, it is easy to see by induction the the 5th row of $P^k$ will always be $(0~0~0~0~1)$ which does not have strictly positive entries. Hence the matrix cannot be primitive.